# Entity framework creates new record when SaveChanges is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two entities:

```
public class Order:Entity
{
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class User:Entity
{
   public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Next, I create order:

```
var order = _orderService.CreateTransientOrder(orderNumbers, PcpSession.CurrentUser);
PcpSession.Order = order;
```

this is `CreateTransientOrder`. It's only create `Order`, but not save into database:

```
public Order CreateTransientOrder(string orderNumbers, User currentUser)
{
   ...fill fields
   order.User = currentUser;
   return order;
}
```

Now it's all ok. Next, I save order to the database:

```
_orderService.CreateOrder(PcpSession.Order);
```

This is `CreateOrder`:

```
public void CreateOrder(Order order)
{
    order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
    _repository.Save(order);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is my `Save` method of repository:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntity
{
    _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
}
```

When the `SaveChanges` is called in the database creates new user with new ID and order have new User_Id. In the debugger in the `CreateOrder` method, Id is equal current user. Where is a problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is probably not being tracked by the context. When you add order to the context it also adds the related entities and then on save changes creates a new user (or attempts to). `Attach()` the user to the context before you call `_context.Set<T>().Add(entity);`.

Comment: I'm using generic context. I don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: @user1260827 do you have the User foreign key avaliable in Order? That is, instead of using `order.User = currentUser` set the association with `order.UserId = currentUser.UserId`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is not related with the code you have provided. It seems to be related to where you are initializing `PcpSession.CurrentUser`.

It seems `PcpSession.CurrentUser` object is not attached to the context. Either fetch this entity to the context before making you `Order` related calls or attach it.

Answer (score 0):

You need attach your Entity if not attach in context.

for exemple in Repository Generic

```
> public void Add(T entity)
>         {
>             entity.Create = DateTime.Now;
>             db.Set<T>().Attach(entity);  // Add Line 
>             db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
>             Save();
>         }
```

I do not know if it's clean but it regulates the problem